# Python raw_input() replacement that uses a configurable text editor

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a replacement for raw_input() that would use a configurable text editor like vim as the interface to to the user.

The ideal workflow would be like this:

1. Your python script is running, and makes a call to my_raw_input().
2. Vim (or emacs, or gedit, or any other text editor) opens w/ a blank document
3. You type some text into the document, then save and exit
4. The python script resumes running, with the contents of the file as the return value of my_raw_input().

If you're familiar with git, this is the experience when using `git commit`, where the editor is configured via [core.editor](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration). Other utilities like `crontab -e` also do this.

Ultimately, I would like this my_raw_input() function to also take an optional string w/ the default input contents, which the user could then edit.

## Research so far

- [os.exec](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execl) replaces the current process with the editor command, but does not return. Ie, your python script exits when vim starts.
- [popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) does not start the child process interactively, there is no user interface displayed.
- vim has a `-` command-line parameter to read from stdin, but nothing to write to stdout with `:w`.
- I took a look at the [code for git](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/run-command.c), which I can't follow at all.

Is this possible?

## Edit

Good answers so far. I also found the [mecurial code](http://selenic.com/repo/hg-stable/file/2770d03ae49f/mercurial/ui.py) that's doing the same thing. I also came up with an example that works from looking at the [crontab code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/cron/cron-35/crontab/crontab.c), but it looks like it's needlessly complicated compared to some of the responses.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import tempfile


def raw_input_editor(default=None, editor=None):
    ''' like the built-in raw_input(), except that it uses a visual
    text editor for ease of editing. Unline raw_input() it can also
    take a default value. '''

    editor = editor or get_editor()

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='r+') as tmpfile:

        if default:
            tmpfile.write(default)
            tmpfile.flush()

        child_pid = os.fork()
        is_child = child_pid == 0

        if is_child:
            os.execvp(editor, [editor, tmpfile.name])
        else:
            os.waitpid(child_pid, 0)
            tmpfile.seek(0)
            return tmpfile.read().strip()


def get_editor():
    return (os.environ.get('VISUAL')
        or os.environ.get('EDITOR')
        or 'vi')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print raw_input_editor('this is a test')
```

Comment: You simply have to write a temp file and fork, then exec.

Comment: @Keith: No need to `fork` and `exec` yourself in Python, that's what the `subprocess` module is for.

Comment: @DietrichEpp To each his own. ;-) I actually find the low-level posix functions easier to use.

Comment: @Keith: Really?  You find `fork` and `exec` easier than `Popen`?  How do you close all of the unneeded file handles?

Comment: @Keith: And to write cross-platform code, I'm guessing you write one version with `fork` and `exec` and a bunch of auxiliary code, another version that calls `win32api.CreateProcess`, etc.?

Comment: @DietrichEpp with os.close(). You can do everything using just the os module. But then I only run on Linux, which has forkpty, openpty, etc. Of course I've wrapped that into reusable objects and have been using that since before the subprocess module existed.

Comment: @abarnert I should mention that I only run on Linux.

Comment: @Keith: So it sounds like you yourself don't use `fork` and `exec`, but you use a library you've written which uses those functions to duplicate functionality in the `subprocess` module, and writing this library is easier than using an existing one which has been around since 2004?

Comment: @DietrichEpp I still sometimes use low-level fork-exec for some things, when I want to have more control or reduce dependencies. But mostly I do use my library. I wrote my library well before 2004, before subprocess existed. I still prefer it over subprocess because I consider it to be more "pythonic".

Comment: @Keith: So how about this: If someone has your wrapper library, and only cares about linux, use that; otherwise, use subprocess, unless they need Python 2.3 compatibility.

Comment: A bold claim (your code is more pythonic than python code?).  Nonetheless, when a reader of this site doesn't have access to your classes wrapped into higher-level objects, it's better to recommend using subprocess over fork/exec madness.

Comment: @abarnert yes, that's what I usually recommend. However, fork/exec is not madness if you are accustomed to that pattern. In fact, it is a standard, C-like pattern that closely resembles the pattern found in Stevens' book. The subprocess moudle uses an obscure, custom pattern unique to it.

Comment: @Keith: Forget wim's "madness" comment; he's clearly right that neither the OP nor most future readers will have access to your wrapper, which means the recommendation to use it doesn't add much.

Comment: @abarnert Nowhere in this thread did I recommend using it. However, it IS open-source and readily available by subversion checkout. So anyone can use it if they want.

Comment: @DietrichEpp BTW, the subprocess module does not handle pty, which you will need if you are going to interact with a subprocess that uses the pty/tty directly in raw mode (such as most password requests or full-screen applications like Vim).

Comment: @Keith: Isn't that what `preexec_fn` is for?

Comment: @DietrichEpp No, that is called in the child process. The parent won't have the master side fd then.

Comment: @wim The code I mentioned (but did not recommend) is open-source and available to anyone. In fact, the subprocess module has some limitations that my code does not have, such as working through a pty instead of pipes (which you will need for some types of supprocesses). Checking exit status is also easier, among other things.

Comment: Interesting (I generally use pexpect for those kind of tasks).  Have you considered contributing your code to python devs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You write the data to a temporary file, and then read it when the editor returns.  If you run `git commit` you'll notice that git is doing the same thing.

There is no extra step to starting a program interactively, as long as the child process has `stdin` and `stdout` wired to a terminal it will be interactive.

There is a gotcha with working with editors -- many of them will save files by writing a temporary file in the same directory and moving it over the old file.  This makes the save operation completely atomic (ignoring that the power might go out) but means that we have to re-open the temporary file after the editor runs, since our old file handle will point to a file that is no longer part of the file system (but it's still on disk).

This gotcha means that we can't use `TemporaryFile` or `NamedTemporaryFile`, we have to use a lower-level facility so we can close the file descriptor and re-open the file without deleting it.

```
import tempfile
import subprocess
import os

def edit(data):
    fdes = -1
    path = None
    fp = None
    try:
        fdes, path = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.txt', text=True)
        fp = os.fdopen(fdes, 'w+')
        fdes = -1
        fp.write(data)
        fp.close()
        fp = None

        editor = (os.environ.get('VISUAL') or
                  os.environ.get('EDITOR') or
                  'nano')
        subprocess.check_call([editor, path])

        fp = open(path, 'r')
        return fp.read()
    finally:
        if fp is not None:
            fp.close()
        elif fdes >= 0:
            os.close(fdes)
        if path is not None:
            try:
                os.unlink(path)
            except OSError:
                pass

text = edit('Hello, World!')
print(text)
```

The Git sample code is so complicated because it's not using a nice high-level library like Python's `subprocess` module.  If you read the `subprocess` module source code, big chunks of it will look like the linked Git source code (except written in Python instead of C).

Comment: +1. But you should probably put `f` in a `with` block (I think `tempfile` is self-contexting; if not, `closing` should work); your existing code doesn't close `f` when it throws. Also, can't you simplify this a bit with `subprocess.check_call`?

Comment: Nice use of the EDITOR environment variable - it's always irritating when tools do not honor this setting.

Comment: @abarnert: Do people use `VISUAL` in the wild?  I thought it was basically defunct, and now nothing more than an alias for `EDITOR`, since only two people in the world use non-visual editors.  If `DISPLAY` is unset then `emacs` and `gvim` work fine.

Comment: @abarnert: "Non-visual editor" means editors like `ed`, not editors like `vi` and `emacs`.  This use of the `VISUAL` is non-standard.  If you want to launch separate editors, use a wrapper script `#!/bin/sh if test -z "$DISPLAY" ; then exec emacsclient "$@" ; else exec emacs "$@" ; fi`, I don't see why every application would be expected to do this test since it's not portable in the first place.

Comment: @abarnert: I'd also like to know which version of Git does that, because 1.7 doesn't (it *always* uses `VISUAL` over `EDITOR`).  See [VISUAL versus EDITOR](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/visual-vs-editor-whats-the-difference).

Comment: You're right, I'm misusing VISUAL, but "git version 1.7.10.2 (Apple Git-33)" on OS X 10.8.2 seems to do what I want. But you're _again_ right that I should be writing a smarter wrapper and using that (although checking for `$DISPLAY` is not the right thing to switch on, because you can (and usually do) have a local Aqua session without any X session. At any rate we're getting way off subject here.

Comment: FYI. On the Mac OS X, this sample works for nano, but not for vi/vim. For OSX/vim combo, the edit() function returns the original data instead of the modified one. On PC-BSD, it works for both editors. I think it is a bug either of OS X, or OS X build of vim.

Comment: @HaiVu: Hey, you're right!  I think on OS X, Vim might swap out files when it saves, *which is exactly what it should do.*  Fixed.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Fix verified for OS=(OSX,BSD), editor=(nano,vim), VISUAL=(unset,nano,vim), EDITOR=(unset,nano,vim). Congratulation and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a temporary file name, for the editor to store its stuff in. You could use [`tempfile.mkstemp()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp) for that. If you want to put some contents in that file, you can do that.

For running the command, [`subprocess.check_call()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) seems like the correct tool for the job, since python waits until this command returns, and raises an exception when the subprocess fails. Roughly:

```
import os
import tempfile
import subprocess

def my_raw_input(default=''):
    tf, tn = tempfile.mkstemp()
    os.close(tf)
    with open(tn) as tf:
        tf.write(default)
    rv = subprocess.check_call(['emacs', tn])
    with open(tn) as f:
        data = f.read()
    os.unlink(tn)
    return data
```

You can of course customize which editor to use, et cetera.

Comment: I think you're better off with `tempfile` than `os.tempnam`. Also it doesn't do the "take an optional string w/ the default input contents" that the OP requested.

Comment: Yeah, tempfile is better. Fixed that.

Comment: OK, but `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` is still better than `tempfile.mkstemp`. For example, if `check_call` throws, you're going to leave the temporary file behind. You could put a `try:/finally:` around it, but why make things harder on yourself?

Comment: With `NamedTemporaryFile` on Windows NT, you have to close the file (which by default deletes it) before the editor can open it.

Comment: This solution won't work: mkstemp() returns a tuple of (handle, filename), where handle is really an int. You will get error at tf.write() because tf is an int.

Comment: This will leak a file handle since `tf` is never closed.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: The `with` statement will automatically close the file after the nested block of code. See http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example

Comment: @RolandSmith: The `with` statement will only close the file handle opened by `open(tn)`.  It will not close the file handle `tf`.  They both refer to the same logical file, but they are separate file handles and must both be closed.  If you don't believe me, try doing it in a loop -- the loop will crash somewhere around 1000 cycles at most.

Comment: This is further confused by the fact that the `tf` variable is used twice.  To clarify: the first `tf` returned by `tempfile.mkstemp()` is not closed and leaks a file descriptor.  It is a raw file descriptor not wrapped by a Python file object, so the garbage collector will not automatically close it.  It will always leak.

Comment: The document stated that mkstemp() returns (handle, filename), where handle was the result of os.open(), which is an int. You can use this handle via os.write() and close it via os.close().