# Redirect text from editor directly to python script

Tags: python, git, vim

is there a way to open text editor like vim or gedit from python script and then redirect typed text from text editor back directly to python script so I could save it in database?
Something like git commit command which opens external text editor and on exit saves commit message but not into file.

Comment: Well, you can do exactly what git does: create a temporary file, edit it with vim, wait for Vim to exit and parse the file.

Comment: I would like to avoid creating [temp file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168083/). But if there's no other way then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would end up depending too much on $EDITOR specific behaviour without a tempfile. The tempfile module deals with the choice of a tempdir and tempfilename so you will not have to. Try the following.

manedit.py:

```
    import os
    import tempfile
    import subprocess

    data = '6 30 210 2310 30030'

    mefile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile( delete=False )
    # delete=False otherwise delete on close() 
    mefile.write( data )
    mefile.close()

    subprocess.call( [ os.environ.get('EDITOR','') or 'vim', mefile.name ] )
    # unset EDITOR or EDITOR='' -> default = vim
    # block here

    mefile = open( mefile.name, 'r' )
    newdata = mefile.read()
    mefile.close()
    os.remove( mefile.name )

    print( newdata )
```

And then try the following commands to verify each scenario.
Replace ed with an editor that differs from your $EDITOR

```
    python manedit.py

    env EDITOR= python manedit.py

    env EDITOR=ed python manedit.py

    env -u EDITOR python manedit.py
```

The pitfall:
The script blocks only while EDITOR is running. An editor may just open a new window on an existing editor session and return, suggesting that the manual edit session completed. However I know no such editor.

edit:
If you are interested specifically in vim or you want to see how specific such thing can get, see the following:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html
http://petro.tanrei.ca/2010/8/working-with-vim-and-ipython.html
http://www.freehackers.org/VimIntegration

Comment: Works as it should and thanks for additional info.